# How to set Prometheus Alertmanager externalURL and generatorURL via configuration

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

How to set `externalURL` and `generatorURL`？

Is it possible to set the URL via configuration file or environment variable?

Who can help me？

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on where you're setting them. Both prometheus and alertmanager have the externalURL field as an option, and can be set via command line arguments, e.g.

```
--web.external-url=https://my-domain.com/alertmanager/
```

So if you're spinning them up as containers/binaries, you'll want to add in that argument and pass the values in.

If you're using kubestack prometheus, you can set these values at the appropriate paths, i.e. [alertmanager.alertmanagerConfig.externalURL](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L518)

From what I can gather, the generatorURL is simply based on the [externalURL](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/905#issuecomment-548600703) though none of the documentation seems to say this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

if you use docker composer, the command is:

1、change prometheus web.external-url:

```
prometheus:
image: prom/prometheus:latest
container_name: prometheus
volumes:
  - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
  - prometheus_data:/prometheus
command:
  - "--web.external-url=http://182.42.xxx.xxx:9090"
```

2、change alertmanager web.external-url:

```
alertmanager:
image: prom/alertmanager:latest
container_name: alertmanager
volumes:
  - ./alertmanager:/etc/alertmanager
command:
  - "--web.external-url=http://182.42.xxx.xxx:9093"
```

and then externalURL and generatorURL will ok